# How replicate database between two database with Oracle esb middleware?

Tags: database, replication, esb

I have two SQL Server databases with the same version.
there is a Oracle bus service between the two SQL Server database.
I want transaction replication between two database,two database located in different cities.
How do I configure Transactional Replication between the two Database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDC, but if you want to replicate an entire SQL database real-time then either use mirroring (which will become phased out) or Always on Availability Groups (recommended by MS going forward). An ESB is for message-oriented communication, not for replication.

Comment: Can esb used for replication?

Comment: An ESB is for a SOA.  Replication is a vendor specific technology which encompasses extremely complex processes.  The vendor is the expert on their system (in your case Microsoft), use their tools, or a third party tool that specializes in replication.  Do not try to do it over an ESB.  That's my advice.